# Font Awesome Flutter Can't Use thin

Tags: flutter, icons, font-awesome

i am currently using Font Awesome Flutter package for icons but i cant use the other versions of icons like light,solid,thin etc.

would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `font_awesome_flutter` pub.dev latest dependency (10.4.0):

> The free Font Awesome Icon pack available as set of Flutter Icons -
> based on font awesome version 6.2.1.

> This icon pack includes only the **free** icons offered by Font Awesome
> out-of-the-box. If you have purchased the pro icons and want to enable
> support for them, please see the instructions below.

> **Enable pro icons**
>
> ❗ By importing pro icons you acknowledge that it is your obligation to
> keep these files private. This includes not uploading your package to
> a public github repository or other public file sharing services.
>
> Go to the location of your custom font_awesome_flutter version (see
> setup) Download the web version of font awesome pro and open it Move
> all .ttf files from the webfonts directory and icons.json from
> metadata to path/to/your/font_awesome_flutter/lib/fonts. Replace
> existing files. Run the configurator. It should say "Custom icons.json
> found" It may be required to run flutter clean in apps who use this
> version for changes to appear.

For more details check the whole package on pub.dev:
[font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter)

Comment: well that explains everything :D